# Why I am not able to fit a sigmoid function to this data using scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

With the code below I am not able to fit a sigmoid function to my dataset. 
However, if I add an offset `t = x + 50 -x0` in code below, it fits nicely.

Shouldn't `x0` take care of the fitting?

---

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

listA = np.array([-110,-105,-100,-95,-90,-85,-80,-75,-70,-65,-60,-55,-50,-45])
listB = np.array([1,1,1,1,0.926470588,0.852941176,0.616803279,0.371212121,
                  0.191066998,0.088565022,0.06684492,0.019855596,0.015517241,0])

def sigmoid(x,x0,k,y0):
    t = x -x0                 
    y = y0-1/(1 + np.exp(-k*t))
    return y

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, listA, listB)
print popt ,pcov    

x = np.linspace(-110,-45,50)

y = sigmoid(x, *popt)

pylab.plot(listA, listB, 'o', label='data')
pylab.plot(x,y, label='fit')
pylab.ylim(-0.05, 1.05)
pylab.legend(loc='best')
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You're running into a classic case of initial condition sensitivity. The `curve_fit` function accepts the keyword parameter `p0`, which lets you choose an initial "guess" for the free parameters of your function (in your case, `x0`, `k`, and `y0`).

When no `p0` is supplied, scipy assumes that all parameters [will start at one](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit). For your function, this means that the denominator of the sigmoid will very close to zero, so the function values blow up. This confounds the solver and results in a poor solution.

Unfortunately, there's no one solution to this problem, as it requires understand of the dynamics of the function you're trying to fit. In your case, supplying a `p0` of `(-30, 1, 0)` will allow the solver to converge to a decent solution.

Comment: Thanks perimosocordiae......  that make sense.. is there a R-square or regression scoe output which I can get  from for curve_fit which will help me guess such issue....

Comment: The assumption on `p0` is incorrect though, which leads you to an incorrect analysis. However, your statement "classic case of initial condition sensitivity" is True, as well as your last paragraph.

Comment: @vivekbecks yes, always check the value of `pcov`. If it's `inf`, something went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the problem deals with huge numbers, making the curve-fitting algorithm to diverge quickly.

The (default) initial guess, `p0`, for `curve_fit` is an array of all ones:

> p0 : None, scalar, or M-length sequence
>       Initial guess for the parameters.  If None, then the initial
>       values will all be 1 (if the number of parameters for the function
>       can be determined using introspection, otherwise a ValueError
>       is raised).

for your problem that means `[1,1,1]`. Using already the first of your x0-values, `-110`, that will result in the argument of the exponential to be: `-1 * (-110-1)` resulting in `np.exp(111)` which is a *huge* number, far larger than the constant 1 that it gets added to. Even for small variations in the initial guess for `x0`, the result would be that the fraction that gets summed up with `y0` is almost zero.  That's why you also see that for your problem, `popt` would return `[1, 1, .51]`: the algorithm didn't find small variations in `x0` to have any significant influence on the outcome (`y`).

The solution is indeed to supply a decent guess. The variations that the algorithm will use for the parameters depend on the magnitude of these parameters too. Supplying `[-45, 1, 1]` will also result in a good solution, as will an initial guess of `-90` for `x0`: just make sure the horizontal offset is at least "close" to the values of the independant variable (the values of `listA` in your case).